# Why when I click messagebox OK button the close code not execute?

Tags: c#

I have windows form application and I want to prevent making duplicate orders for the same patient

and I check if the patient have order today and if I try to make another order it will show message

patient have order today then when click ok button I need to close the window , but its not closing the window when click ok button ,

This is the code I used :

```
var patientNumber = order.GetPatientNumber(Convert.ToInt32(textPatientID.Text),Program.branch_id); // int?
            bool patientExists = patientNumber.HasValue;
            if (patientExists == true)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("PATIENT HAS ORDER TODAY ", "DUPLICATE ORDER ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }

            }
```

I tried also to close the form without if but also not closing :

```
var patientNumber = order.GetPatientNumber(Convert.ToInt32(textPatientID.Text),Program.branch_id); // int?
            bool patientExists = patientNumber.HasValue;
            if (patientExists == true)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("PATIENT HAS ORDER TODAY ", "DUPLICATE ORDER ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
               
                    this.Close();
               

            }
```

why its not closing what's the wrong please your help ?

Comment: Since your dialog has the only `OK` button, I suggest removing `if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)` and call `this.Close();` without any condition

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I tried it also without if but not closing I updated the question

Comment: Time to debug: please, put *breakpoint* on `if (patientExists == true)` and check `patientExists` value, put another *breakpoint* on `this.Close();` - is it executed? Does your form have `FormClose` or `FormClosing` event handlers?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes sir its working now its my mistake I added the code in 3 voids in (private void FRM_ORDERS_Load) and in patient list button (private void lblPatientList_Click) and in (private void btnSearch_Click)  test search button I updated the code in buttons voids and not updated the code for void when form load when I updated the load void with this.close its working now thank you so much please add the answer its working without IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no reason in

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
```

check, since the dialog has the *only* `OK` button:

```
if (order
    .GetPatientNumber(int.Parse(textPatientID.Text), Program.branch_id)
    .HasValue) {
  MessageBox.Show(
    "PATIENT HAS ORDER TODAY", 
    "DUPLICATE ORDER", 
     MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
     MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

  Close();
}
```